# ASP.net: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for an existing object

Tags: asp.net

I'm using **MSCaptcha** control in **asp.net 4.0** web application. I've placed provided **.dll** and **.xml** files in the **Bin** folder and added `<%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="cc1" %>` in top of page. 
It's how I use it in page:

```
<cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha1" runat="server"
                 CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="4"
                 CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="300"
                 CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMinTimeout="1"
                 CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" FontColor = "#529E00" />
```

And in code behind I use it like this:

```
If Page.FindControl("Captcha1").ToString = "MSCaptcha.CaptchaControl" Then
    Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(webCaptcha.Text.Trim())

    If Captcha1.UserValidated Then
        addComment()
    Else
        webWrongCaptcha.Text = "Captcha is wrong!"
    End If
Else
    Response.Redirect("contact.aspx?c=e")
End If
```

But I face this error if user click the button after `CaptchaMaxTimeout`:

```
Line 7:              Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(webCaptcha.Text.Trim())
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is `null`: `Captcha1`, `webCaptcha` or `webCaptcha.Text`?

Comment: it's not `webCaptcha` nor `webCaptcha.Text`, but not sure about `Captcha1`

Comment: Because I tried `Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha("foo")` and faced same error.

Comment: answer provided against another similar query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232819/ms-captcha-timeout-duration-in-registration-form-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your logic in a statement that determines if the Captcha is null, prior to calling it's properties.  If it is, handle the error by sending a message to the client letting them known they exceeded the timeout and they need try again.

Comment: I think `If Page.FindControl("Captcha1").ToString = "MSCaptcha.CaptchaControl" Then` does this, yes?

Comment: @Maysam Shouldn't you be using something like `If CType(Page.FindControl("Captcha1"), CaptchaControl) Is Not Nothing Then`? That string conversion stuff looks like it could be a little fragile.

Comment: None of the above options worked for me, I was forced to write a `Try` - `Catch` block around my `CaptchaControl1.ValidateCaptcha`

Answer (score 0):

Add the EnableViewState="False" to the code: